# Ljung-Box and Durbin-Watson tests for svarest object in R

Tags: r, statistics

I estimated an SVAR model in R, using the SVAR command from the vars package. I first estimated a VAR model, saved it as varModel. This object is of class varest. Then I used it, and the restriction matrices to estimate the SVAR model, and saved the output as svarModel. This object is of class svarsest. Now, when I tried to use the serial.test command for this test, but it needs a varest object.

How do I proceed?

Comment: If you want answers here you will provide a [MCVE]